# iOS 8 custom music player button in control center

Tags: ios, audio-player

My app doesn't allow you to go to the previous track, so i would like to replace that previous button in the control center and the lock screen with a star button like the picture below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyDFe.jpg

Is that possible?

I tried to set "MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackQueueIndex" to 1 and "MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackQueueCount" to 1 into nowPlayingInfo to let iOS know there his no previous track but that doesn't help.

Any clue?